# generate array from php while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I want to run a while(or any) loop to output a small list of dates as an array

```
$start = $day = strtotime("-1 day");
$end = strtotime('+6 day');
while($day < $end)
{
    echo  date('d-M-Y', $day) .'<br />';
    $day = strtotime("+1 day", $day) ;
}
```

This works fine for printing, but I want to save it as an array (and insert it in a mysql db).
Yes! I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to create a array, you need to first initialize it outside your loop (because of variable scoping)

```
$start = $day = strtotime("-1 day");
$end = strtotime('+6 day');
$dates = array(); //added
while($day < $end)
{
    $dates[] = date('d-M-Y', $day); // modified
    $day = strtotime("+1 day", $day) ;
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($dates);
echo "</pre>";
```

you can then use your dates using either `foreach` or `while`

foreach approach :

```
foreach($dates as $date){
     echo $date."<br>";
}
```

while approach :

```
$max =  count($dates);
$i = 0;
while($i < $max){
    echo $dates[$i]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: The notes were helpful as well as the options.

Answer (score 5):

```
$arr = Array();
while(...) {
   $arr[] = "next element";
   ...
}
```

The `[]` adds a new element to an array, just like `push()` but without the overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is just:

```
$start = $day = strtotime("-1 day");
$end = strtotime('+6 day');
$arr = array();
while($day < $end)
{
    $arr[] = date('d-M-Y', $day);
    $day = strtotime("+1 day", $day) ;
}

// Do stuff with $arr
```

the `$arr[] = $var` is the syntax for appending to an array in PHP. Arrays in php do not have a fixed size and therefore can be appended to easily.