# Read next cell in same column CSV to XML using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, csv

I am reading in a comma delimited CSV file using PHP and outputting it as an xml file.

I am reading the CSV file in as an Array where each field is appointed to a key in the array.

Column F (See example CSV file) has multiple IDs in the same column under each other. The issue that I am having is that when the file is being read, the 2nd, 3rd and 4th cell in column F are going to its own array.

How can I loop through column F so that I can print out each ID?

**Current Code**

```
function process_downloads() {

clearstatcache();

$handle = opendir( DOWNLOAD_DIR );

while( ( $filename = readdir( $handle ) ) !== false ) {

    $input_filename = DOWNLOAD_DIR."/".$filename;

    if( is_file( $input_filename ) ) {

        $file_age = ( time() - filectime( $input_filename ) );

        if( $file_age >= 2 ) {

            converttoxml( $input_filename );

        }
    }

}

    closedir( $handle );

}



function converttoxml( $input_filename ) {


 $file_parts = pathinfo( $input_filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME );



 $buffer = file( $input_filename );


for( $counter = 0; $counter < count( $buffer ); $counter++ ) {


    $fields = split(',' , $buffer[ $counter ] );


    print_r($fields);



}
```

**The Output of print_r($fields)**

```
Array
(
[0] => 23456
[1] => Foo
[2] => Bar
[3] => 
[4] => br
[5] => 7854265478


 Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 7854147854


Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 7985415487


Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 7459658741
```

I am reading in the csv file and converting it to xml. How can I add the $fields[5] all into one array? As you can see, the first array is the first row of the csv file. I want one array but with all the $fields[5] values under one array.

How can I do that and loop through it?

**How I am assigning each key to a variable right now**

$fields is the name of the array

```
$var1  =   trim( $fields[ 5 ] );
```

**CSV file**

[image: The CSV file that is being read]

Any ideas?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but do you mean using something like `$var1[] = trime($fields[5]);` similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105419/generate-array-from-php-while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your csv array is consistent in which column F is always 'broken' into exactly 4 rows, you can try the following.

```
$i = 0;
$ii = 0;
$data = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($ii > 3) {
        $ii = 0;
        $i++;
    }

    if($ii == 0) {
        $data[$i][0] = $row[0];
        $data[$i][1] = $row[1];
        $data[$i][2] = $row[2];
        $data[$i][3] = $row[3];
        $data[$i][4] = $row[4];
    }

    $data[$i][5][] = $row[5];
    $ii++;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What happens if column F is not always 4 rows? I have another field which I use to determine how many rows there are in Column F. Something like.....if(trim( $fields[ 3 ] ) != " " ) then use the value of $fields which will be the same amount of rows in column F. So if fields[3] is 7, then there will be 7 rows in column F. if fields[3] is 25, there will be 25 rows in column F etc.

Comment: if that's the case, replace "if($ii > 3)" with "if($ii > ($fields[3] - 1))"